# AJAX: How to Read JSON Data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax, object

I am trying to get json data from url. Here's the js

```
var myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  myRequest.open('GET', 'URL that has JSON format');
  myRequest.onload = function() {
    var myData = JSON.parse(myRequest.responseText);
    console.log(myData);
  };
myRequest.send();
```

The JSON data format is like this

```
"ING":
    [
        {
            "#":1,
            "Team":"Manchester City",
            "Main":37,
            "Poin":97
        },
        {
            "#":2,
            "Team":"Manchester United",
            "Main":37,
            "Poin":78
        },
        {
            "#":3,
            "Team":"Tottenham Hotspur",
            "Main":37,
            "Poin":74
        },
        {
            "#":4,
            "Team":"Liverpool",
            "Main":37,
            "Poin":72
        },
        {
            "#":5,
            "Team":"Chelsea",
            "Main":37,
            "Poin":70
        }
    ]
}
```

for example i want to fetch Chealsea. How can i achieve that? i know that i have to change

> console.log(myData);

What should i do?  Thanks

Comment: thanks @cale_b for suggest

Comment: Your question is actually unclear.  How do you know you want to acces `Chelsea`?  Since it's the 5th item in _an array_, we need to know - are you looking for a way to _find_ information? Or simply how to _access_ it? Accessing is simple: `var data = myData.ING[4].Team`, or `myData['ING'][4]['Team']` ... but _finding_ the record with the team of chelsea is different altogether...

Comment: you can use simple filter to achieve that.

Comment: var chelseaTeam = obj.ING.filter(function(team){ team.Team === 'Chelsea';})

Comment: @cale_b sorry if my question is unclear, actualy i need simply to access it. myData['ING'][4]['Team'] is what i needed. Thank you.

Comment: then, what should i do with this post? should i delete it?

Comment: @dany - leave it.  The community will eventually close it as duplicate, but the question will remain as a "flagpost" for others searching in the same way that you posted the question.

Comment: @dany I added answer, hope it will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find()` to find something in an array. I changed Chelsea with Liverpool, as they will win the Champions League this year. Who cares about another team then...

```js
let obj = {"ING":
    [
        {
            "#":1,
            "Team":"Manchester City",
            "Main":37,
            "Poin":97
        },
        {
            "#":2,
            "Team":"Manchester United",
            "Main":37,
            "Poin":78
        },
        {
            "#":3,
            "Team":"Tottenham Hotspur",
            "Main":37,
            "Poin":74
        },
        {
            "#":4,
            "Team":"Liverpool",
            "Main":37,
            "Poin":72
        },
        {
            "#":5,
            "Team":"Chelsea",
            "Main":37,
            "Poin":70
        }
    ]
}
console.log(obj.ING.find(e => e.Team === 'Liverpool'));
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-an-array-of-javascript-objects

Comment: Oh, I did.  But with 37k rep, I'd expect _you_ to do that as well :)

Comment: Sorry, just answered to change it to Liverpool @cale_b

Answer (score 1):

You can use callback, promises or async/await. Here's a way that you can use callback to get and use the retrieved data:

```
function getUrl(url, callback) {
  var myRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  myRequest.open('GET', url);
  myRequest.onload = function() {
    var myData = JSON.parse(myRequest.responseText);
    console.log(myData);
    callback(myData);
  };
  myRequest.send();
}
```

and you request and use your data like so:

```
getUrl('URL for JSON DATA', function(data) {
  // find chealsea
  var chealsea = data.ING.find(function(entry) { return entry.Team === 'Chealsea' });
  console.log(chealsea);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To read a JSON. 
Notice the bracket type,

if it has [], then treat that part as an array, if it has curly braces {3, then as an object.

to access Array object, use index, like 0, 1, 2 ...
to access objects, you can use dot notation `your_object.key`or`your_object["key"]`

```
in your case, we can read it like

let json = {"ING":[{...}]}

json["ING"][0]["SOME_KEY"] ...
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```js
var myData = {
 "ING": [{
   "#": 1,
   "Team": "Manchester City",
   "Main": 37,
   "Poin": 97
  },
  {
   "#": 2,
   "Team": "Manchester United",
   "Main": 37,
   "Poin": 78
  },
  {
   "#": 3,
   "Team": "Tottenham Hotspur",
   "Main": 37,
   "Poin": 74
  },
  {
   "#": 4,
   "Team": "Liverpool",
   "Main": 37,
   "Poin": 72
  },
  {
   "#": 5,
   "Team": "Chelsea",
   "Main": 37,
   "Poin": 70
  }
 ]
};

var res = myData.ING.filter(obj => obj.Team == "Chelsea");

console.log(res[0].Team);
```